# Plot ROC curve [mmdetection]

Tags: python-3.x, google-colaboratory

I have a question regarding plotting the ROC curve after training and testing my model using mmdetection. Since I don't have test labels.txt, could someone please advise me on the next steps to take? Any suggestions or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

I would like to ask for some advice on how to plot the ROC curve. I haven't been successful in doing so.